# WPF Material Design Progress Dialog not shown during a task execution

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I try to open a material design dialog while some task is executed in the background. Therefore, I wrapped my DockPanel with the DialogHost `<materialDesign:DialogHost>` and overloaded the the `Show` method with the callback delegates.

When I click a Button, a progress dialog during the task execution shoud be shown, e.g.

```
private async void LoadConfigButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            var dialogContent = new TextBlock
            {
                Text = "Loading.... Please wait.",
                Margin = new Thickness(20)
            };
            await DialogHost.Show(dialogContent,
                new DialogOpenedEventHandler((object senderDialog, DialogOpenedEventArgs args) =>
                {
                // DoStuffMethod();
                }));

}
```

Now, I see the progress dialog, but only after the `"Do stuff method"` has been completed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is no indication if your

```
// DoStuffMethod();
```

is an async method as well.   If it isn't, have the Dispatcher execute the work asynchronously to prevent the block

I.E.

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () => DoStuffMethod());
```

I just googled this, but am also remembering that the dispatcher object should have an InvokeAsync() method you can call as well.

You can access the dispatcher as shown above, but your control should also have a Dispatcher property available that can be used the same way.

Comment: I tried this, too. But it breaks my application because of the ressources sharing between the STA thread and things that happen in the DoStuffMethod (return type: void)

Comment: Ahh, you need the dispatcher.   Hang on I'll edit my post

Comment: Same behavior as before. Compiler gives me this Warning: CS1998  C# This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Comment: If you access anything from the UI you must use the UI thread to perform the UI updates.   The apartment thread operates in a manner similar to Javascript, where it can perform multiple pieces of independent work simultaneously as though it were parallel processing, but it's actually just scheduling work on a single thread in chunks for each task it has in it's queue.   The manager of this apartment thread, at least for WPF, is the Dispatcher

Comment: Yeah. youll get that warning if you dont do anything with the awaitable object you jsut created.   If you don't want to see the warning make the call an assignment:  var t = App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () => DoStuffMethod()); and you can even await the end of the execution at some later point when it's more convenient for you.

Comment: Ok. I just want to inform the user about an ongoing operation, so maybe I can show the Dialog in the separate thread/task instead of doing things within the dialog...

Comment: How about using a spinner?   There are many great out of the box spinners you can use in WPF applications

Answer (score 1):

When you call DialogHost.Show, the [DialogOpenedEventHandler is invoked synchronously](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/DialogHost.cs#L282).

If the DoStuffMethod is blocking, it will prevent the dialog from being shown until it completed. If you want to invoked *after* the dialog has already been shown there are a couple choices.

1. Wrap the call inside of a Task.Run. This assumes that it is a void returning method. If it is not you may need to look at one of the other [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1). Be aware this will cause the method to run on a background thread. If there is anything in the method that needs to touch UI elements, you will need to leverage Dispatcher.[Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=netcore-3.1)/[BeginInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke?view=netcore-3.1) as others have mentioned.

   Task.Run(DoStuffMethod);
2. Enqueue the method on the UI's dispatcher. When you use [Dispather.BeginInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke?view=netcore-3.1) the method is enqueued on the current dispatchers queues. This is not a static method so you will need to get an instances of the Dispatcher (this can be a problem if you are doing MVVM, and this code is in your view model). Typically you would either use the Dispatcher property directly on an UI element, or you can access one using the static property Application.Current.Dispatcher.

   var dispatcher = ...

   dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DoStuffMethod);